# GridGain and Memcached Cache Selection

Tags: gridgain

I'm evaluating GridGain as a caching solution for my PHP based web sites.  I'll be using the Memcached interface.  It would be nice to be able to access different caches (i.e. a replicated cache and a local cache) on the same node.  From what I can find, however, it is not possible to select a cache when using the Memcached interface; it just uses the default cache.  The documentation on using the Memcached interface doesn't mention anything about which cache it uses or if a cache can be selected.  Is there a way to specify the cache to use when using the Memcached interface that I have missed or can I only use the default cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use the default cache.

By looking at code on GridGain server side, it looks like you could still specify cache-name in the "extra" space of memcached protocol, but it is not obvious how to achieve it from the memcached client side.

If you can switch to GridGain Client API, then you can freely use any cache you have configured.